# What kind of license to issue for themes development?

Tags: licensing

We are a team of Web Developer and Graphics designer and work on Website themes  for Ragnarok Online.
Our designer use characters, backgrounds from other sources eg;google etc like other graphics designer of Ragnarok, FLYFF other gaming web developers do. But Most of the works are released by Gravity and we credits on footer by mentioning ( **All Registered Trademarks belong to their Respective Owners and Gravity Co.LTD.** )

I would like to know the license available this kind of work or what i can mention on my license to avoid any trouble?

Comment: You need to be more precise. I don't know what is Ragnarok Online, what is FLYFF, etc. You need to be more precise, and also write what are their licenses.

Answer (score 2):

Mentioning with "All Registered Trademarks" is not giving credits, and trademarks don't matter in this case.

You need to have the permission to copy and distribute graphics, code etc. made by other people (with few exception, but not in this case). Credits are not sufficient. So you should check if such permission is given by a license, or you need to get a license from authors (maybe paying him). You need also to be careful about modifying such images. The license should permit it, or you cannot modify images.

Comment: Important: Per default you should consider that you are not having any permission to redistribute/change/* artwork of other people until  you got the permission.